# Hashing & Expectation

Tags: hash

Hash function h:{0,1}^30000→{0,1}^20

A message m is sampled if the first 4 bits of h(m) are all zero.
Let N be the number of messages the detector hashes, and let Y be the number
of messages the detector samples. How large should N be to ensure that E[Y] = 20000?

Any help with this?? Thanks

Comment: Homework, by any chance?

Comment: It depends on the hash function.

Answer (score 2):

This depends entirely on the hash function your using. For instance, here's a (very bad) hash function

```
h(m) = 11111111111111111111
```

Since everything gets mapped to a string of ones, `E[Y]` is zero no matter how many messages are handled. is. So to guarantee an expected value of 20000, you need some criteria on the hash function.

Comment: Say the h(m) = 00001111111111111111
What would happen then?

Comment: Then `E[Y]` = `N` no matter what (since all messages will be sampled). However, say that in the first four bits of `h(m)`, the string '0000' is just as likely to occur as '0001' and '0002' and all the others (a total of 16 possibilities). Then we get `E[Y] = N / 16`. What's going in here is that each hash function obeys a specific statistical distribution, and each distribution has its own set of statistical properties, including the expected value.